# CodeKit Live Refresh Isn't Working

Tags: javascript, webkit, codekit

Just upgraded from CodeKit to CodeKit 2, super excited about using it, but when I try to use the live preview feature in anything but Firefox, I get in a JS alert:

> Failed to establish a connection to CodeKit. Live refreshes will not
>   work.

I've tried using both the Bonjour and non-Bonjour addresses to no avail. Went to the console to find:

> WebSocket connection to 'ws://192.168.1.6:5758/' failed: Error during
>   WebSocket handshake: Status line contains embedded null

(note: the live refresh actually works, the only thing is there's a large annoying red box telling me to restart the connection. This red box doesn't appear in Firefox, but I need to code for WebKit.)

Comment: What version of which browser are you using? Are you running browser plugins? Which version of OS X are you on? Dude... reports without details are virtually impossible to answer.

Comment: @Bryan 
Browser: Chrome 33.0.1750.146, plugins disabled.
OS X: 10.9.2

Comment: @Bryan doesn't work in (plug-ins & extensions disabled): Chrome Canary 35.0.1882.0, Opera 20.0.1387.64, Safari 7.0.2 (9537.74.9).

Works in Firefox 27.0.1 (Firebug installed, deactivated).

Comment: Ok. Until I figure out what's causing it, you should be able to use the Inspector to remove/hide the red box element.

Comment: does this help? @Bryan here's a breakdown from my net internals in Chrome.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_ZwBlPnf3dsMThTblBhUWN4XzA/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had this problem with **CodeKit 2 on Android** but instead of using `my-imac.local:5757` i used my Local IP Address and the same port `http://192.1.2.3:5757` and it **worked perfectly**.

I am using Chrome on **Android 5.0.1** which is the most recent version as of this post.

In case you're not sure how to get your IP Address then hold **Alt Key** and click the wifi [image: WiFi Logo] logo in your menu bar... You should see `IP: 123.45.6.7`

*Note* Remember you must be on the same WiFi network as your computer.

Hope this helps you and/or any future people experiencing the same issue.